# CartThrob: display content if certain product is in package

Tags: cartthrob, conditionals, ecommerce

I'm using CartThrob for e-commerce. I need to display a block of content only if the package displayed contains a product with a certain entry_id. I was assuming I could just wrap the block of content in a conditional that checks the included products for an entry_id? The channel entry_id of the product I need to check for is 23.

If possible, I could also use a tip on how to enable shipping only for packages that contain this product with this entry_id.

Here is my main template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="rides" limit="1" dynamic="no" url_title="{segment_3}"}
            <main role="main" class="inner-page view">
        <p class="read-more"><a href="/pro-rides" class="blue">&laquo; Back to Pro Rides</a></p>
                    <article>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <img src="{ride_img}" alt="{title}, ${ride_price}" />
            <p class="lead">Price: ${ride_price}</p>
            {if ride_body}
            <p>{ride_body}</p>
            {if:else}
            <p>{ride_excerpt}</p>
            {/if}
        </article>
        <section>
            {embed="views/.packages"}
        </section>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Here is the embedded packages template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="store_packages" dynamic="no"}
{if related_ride == "{segment_3}"}
    <ul>
            <li>{title}, {entry_id}: {packages_price} </li>
            {!-- check for product entry_id inclusion --}
            <li><!-- content displayed conditionally --></li>
            {!-- end conditional --}
            <li><p class="read-more"><a href="{entry_id_path=checkout/cart}" class="blue">Purchase Ride now &raquo;</a></p></li>
    </ul>
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finally figuring out how to access the custom cartThrob Package fields (I couldn't find any documentation in the cartThrob docs for this) and used the following:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="store_packages" dynamic="no"}
{if related_ride == "{segment_3}"}
    <ul>
            <li>{title}, {entry_id}: {packages_price} </li>
            {packages}{if "{sub:entry_id}" == "23"}Bring your own Bike{if:elseif "{sub:entry_id}" == "24"}Rent our Bike{/if}{/packages}
            <li><p class="read-more"><a href="{entry_id_path=checkout/cart}" class="blue">Purchase Ride now &raquo;</a></p></li>
    </ul>
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Now off to figure out how to add shipping only to packages that contain this product entry_id!